# Large number of database inserts failing to actually insert on derby database

Tags: sql, eclipse, derby

I'm running Apache Derby server on Eclipse EE.

My issue is that whenever I attempt to insert (relatively) larger numbers of records into the database, it tells me that the operation was successful, but upon inspection many of the records were not actually inserted.

For example, I have an sql file which inserts 400 records in one statement into the database, and there is no issue there, all records are inserted. However, when I attempt to insert with a file that has around 800 records, only about 350 of those records end up being inserted. It inserts the records in the order they are given in the file, and then at a certain point just does not insert them, despite telling me it has succeeded.

Same issue with a file that has 8000 records. Even if I split that one up, only a few of the records are seen within the table.

What could be causing this and how can I solve it?

edit: extra information:

I am loading an sql file into eclipse, setting its connection profile to the derby database, and using the "execute all" command on the file.

Here is a truncated example of the contents of one such file. There would be ~800 lines in this before the semicolon.

```
    INSERT INTO db.GAME VALUES
    (2010, 'South Africa', 2010, 'Mexico', 11, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'Uruguay', 2010, 'France', 11, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'South Africa', 2010, 'Uruguay', 16, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'France', 2010, 'Mexico', 17, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'Mexico', 2010, 'Uruguay', 22, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'France', 2010, 'South Africa', 22, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'Argentina', 2010, 'Nigeria', 12, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'Korea Republic', 2010, 'Greece', 12, 06, 2010, 'Group Match'),
    (2010, 'Greece', 2010, 'Nigeria', 17, 06, 2010, 'Group Match');
```

Upon executing this, the status window will display the contents of the sql file and followed by

```
"(772 rows affected)


Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 1 ms."
```

The SQL Results window has its status as "success" and lists the operation as "INSERT INTO db.GAME..."

I am not sure where to access the derby log of which you speak.

Comment: I think you should start by gathering a lot more information: how are you doing the insert? What tool do you use?  Can you show the code? Can you include the exact output of the insert? What does the Derby log say? What do you mean by "telling me it has succeeded"?

Comment: just added some information, hopefully that should help

Comment: The Derby log is a file named 'derby.log' which should be created in the home directory of the Derby network server, or in the current directory if you are running Derby embedded (See http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp25889.html). It's interesting that you are using a massive number of elements in a 'values' list; you may be hitting some sort of internal limit in Derby. Meanwhile, I don't understand the part where you said "only about 350 of those records end up being inserted", since your output clearly shows "772 rows affected".

Comment: Is it possible that all the rows are in fact being inserted, but Eclipse's SQL Results Window is truncating the output? I know that SQL Squirrel has a configurable "max rows" parameter which you have to explicitly set higher if you are trying to work with a larger number of rows.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I should have actually performed a query to see the the output rather than just looking at the results window.

Comment: However, when you say that I am using a massive number of elements in a values list, what would be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing is fine, actually. Other ways to do this would be: (a) issue N insert statements, (b) write the data to a file and use the IMPORT system procedures, or (c) use the "batch" facilities of JDBC to create a statement batch (requires writing a program). But since what you're doing works, stick with it!

Comment: By the way, can you add your resolution as a separate answer and accept it, so that the question is packaged up nicely for future readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's SQL Results Window was truncating the output.

I should have actually performed a query to see the the output rather than just looking at the results window.